# How do I evolve Kadabra to its final form without trading it?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-third-generation

I play Pokemon Emerald on the computer using VisualBoy Advance, so I can't evolve my Kadabra by trading it. Is there any other way I can turn my Kadabra into Alakazam?

Comment: I believe there's a trainer who will trade you a Kadabra kicking around, somewhere.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @fbueckert Unfortunately there is no such trainer in emerald. See the bulbapedia link in my answer. That trainer is present in Diamond, platinum and pearl.

Comment: Only way I can think of, would be cheating.

Comment: Doesn't VBA support link cable emulation if you run a second instance?

Comment: @Shinrai If it does then you might have a good answer there

Comment: mGBA does support linking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, for the exact reasons you stated.

While it would be possible if one of the ingame traders was willing to trade one, according to the Bulbapedia ingame trade list there is no such trader.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_in-game_trades)

Answer (score 22):

Apparently, there is [at least one offshoot](http://www.vbalink.info/) of Visual Boy Advance (though I've only located the one) which allows for emulation of the GBA Link Cable, and I'm assuming that running two instances of the program and connecting to `localhost` would provide you with local trade functionality.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted. This is entirely true and is how my roommate and I evolved our Kadabra/Haunter when playing leaf green and fire red on VBA.

Comment: @Slurpee that's stupid. One of the asker's assumptions was incorrect (can't trade with an emulator), Shotgun pointed out how to get around it. That's a very good answer.

Answer (score 11):

You have to get a certain emulator (I think it's a plug-in I'm not sure) called VBALink. You can find it here: http://www.vbalink.info/

You can then link up 2 running VGB emulators. You can also follow this video closely if you have any questions:

The first link basically allows you to virtually link up 2 gameboys together. The second link shows you how if you get stuck.

Answer (score -1):

GameShark always helps, or if you trade. Otherwise, no you can't evolve it by yourself.

Comment: Know which GameShark codes would help the OP?